# How do I use an Instagram API to be able to search via location (i.e. city) through preloaded hashtags i.e. sightseeing, tourism etc

Tags: javascript, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to use the Instagram's API to search via city within already preloaded hashtags by myself. In the JavaScript code I have created, I have already got images with the hashtags I have selected to load via geolocation, however I want users to be able to search through these hashtags via the location they are after, for example, a user searching for Mexico and images showing with the hashtags #sightseeing, #tourism etc.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, @jack-kemmish, do you have some [code to show](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It would make easiest to help you then.